# 2023年コミュニティモデレーター選挙

Tags: 討議, モデレーション, 選挙

2023 年度コミュニティモデレーター選挙が実施されます！

選挙は 3 つの段階で実施されます:

1. 立候補
2. 予備選
3. 選挙

候補者人数にもよりますが、通常の選挙期間は 2 から 3 週間ほどです。

詳細は公式の選挙ページをご覧ください。

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/election

どうぞご参加ください！

選挙過程やモデレーター候補についての質問はメタで遠慮なく質問してください。[選挙](/questions/tagged/%e9%81%b8%e6%8c%99)タグをお忘れなく。

Comment: 現時点で候補者への質問5-7が英語ですが、こちらは後で翻訳予定ですか？

Comment: @payaneco ありがとうございます！[選挙用チャット](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146055/2023--)に本選挙が始まってすぐに記載したのですが、こちらにも共有させてください！翻訳済みのものがうまく表示されておりませんので、そちらの反映を取り急ぎ依頼しております 

Comment: 立候補者のみなさま、和訳が反映されるまで、ご参考までに以下をご覧くださいませ‍♀️

Comment: **5. あなたの意見では、モデレーターとは具体的に何をするのでしょう？**

Comment: **6. 質問や回答、コメントなど過去に発言したものすべての横にダイヤモンドマークが加えられ、これから発言することに対してもフィルターがかかります。そのような状況についてどう思いますか？**

Comment: **7. 単に [モデレーターツールへのアクセス (2,000)]($moderatorToolsUrl$)或いは [信頼できるユーザー (4,000)]($trustedUserUrl$) の信用度に達するというのではなく、あなたはモデレーターになることによってさらにどのように効果的になると思いますか？**

Comment: 分かりました。丁寧なリプライありがとうございます。

Comment: @payaneco 、みなさま、反映が完了しました！

Comment: ここでは「注目」というタグはもう必要ないと思います。

Comment: 注目タグをはずしました